# How to attach a file to a nested form in Rails using Capybara attach_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest, rails-activestorage

I'm having trouble attaching a file using Minitest with Capybara in Rails. The problem is that the file field is in a nested form. The nested form gets a random ID and name added to it, so I can't select by these.

Normally when it's not a nested form this works:

```
attach_file("post[featured_image]", "#{Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg")}")
```

But, on the nested form the form field looks like this:

[image]

I thought this should work:

```
within(".image-upload") do
  attach_file('input[type="file"]', "#{Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg")}", make_visible: true)
end
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find file field "input[type=\"file\"]" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="fieldset"
```

I've also tried other methods described in the capybara docs [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method).

Is there a way to do this? The only time I've gotten capybara `attach_file` to work is when I've been able to target the element name as in the `post[featured_image` example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not showing enough HTML to confirm that the input field is actually within the .image-upload fieldset, but assuming it is then it's possible the real file input is actually hidden, and replaced with something else for styling purposes. Additionally the locator passed to attach_file is not CSS it's the id, name, or associated label text (ie 'input[type="file"]' is not valid there).  Given all that there's a number of things you could do

If the file field is visible and the only one in scope then skip the locator

```
attach_file(Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg"))
```

If it's visible and there are multiple in scope then pick the one you want using name or id filter, potentially with a regexp

```
attach_file(Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg"), id: /images_attributes_0_image_file/)
```

If the file field is actually hidden then try

```
attach_file(Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg")) {
   # do whatever the user would do to initiate selecting a file
   # click('Upload File') - etc
}
```

That would be emulating the user as much as possible - if that doesn't work then another approach would be to attempt to force the file input to be visible like

```
attach_file(Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/example-featured-image.jpg"), make_visible: true)
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Walpole! I didn't realize you could use a regex with capybara to select only a portion of the ID. I tried the other methods, but I could not get it to work exactly as the user would experience by emulating clicking on "Choose File." The regex solution worked though. I'm not using the Cocoon gem, but my javascript is doing something similar, so my issue was comparable to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477426/capybara-match-element-id-with-regex.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly - See https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L8 ` for the filters supported by all of Capybaras built-in selector types - attach_file` is using the :file_field selector https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L140

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly As for the other questions you linked to, that's using `all` which like `find` does take CSS by default, `attach_file` is higher level and does not.